# How to use the kubernetes go-client to get the same Pod status info that kubectl gives

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

Using the kubernetes go-client (`k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes`), I know how to get `pod.Status` and I find the `pod.Status.Phase` useful ([docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-phase)). For example, I can output the Pod Status Phase of all Pods using this:

```golang
    ...
    api := clientset.CoreV1()
    pods, err := api.Pods("").List(metav1.ListOptions{})
    for i, pod := range pods.Items {
        podstatusPhase := string(pod.Status.Phase)
        podCreationTime := pod.GetCreationTimestamp()
        age := time.Since(podCreationTime.Time).Round(time.Second)

        podInfo := fmt.Sprintf("[%d] Pod: %s, Phase: %s , Created: %s, Age: %s", i, pod.GetName(), podstatusPhase, podCreationTime, age.String())
        fmt.Println(podInfo)
    }
```

However, the `phase` is a little simplistic in that it only ever shows 5 values (`Pending`, `Running`, `Succeeded`, `Failed`, `Unknown`). I'd rather get the same info that `kubectl get pods` gives in the *Status* column, for example:

```
$ kubectl get pods

NAME                                        READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE     IP             NODE                           NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
moby-dick-cron-scheduler-1564578660-bg4sb   0/2     ContainerCreating   0          178m    <none>         ip-10-30-13-151.ec2.internal   <none>           <none>
notifications-missed-calls-1564564740-js762 0/2     Init:0/1            0          6h49m   <none>         ip-10-30-13-6.ec2.internal     <none>           <none>
antivirus-scanner-cron-1564576740-sd6hh     0/2     Completed           0          3h30m   10.30.13.169   ip-10-30-13-151.ec2.internal   <none>           <none>
```

In particular, I'm interested in `Init:0/1` and `PodInitializing` statuses. The Pods in these statuses just show as "Pending" when using `pod.Status.Phase`.

- `Init:0/1` means the Pod has 1 Init containers and 0 have completed successfully so far. [init containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) run before app containers are started.
- `PodInitializing` means the Pod has already finished executing Init Containers.

Is there a way to get a Status such as `Init:0/1` using `k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes`? or is there no short-cut, and I'd need to re-calculate it the same way kubectl does? I guess it uses Pod Status [Conditions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-conditions) and [container statuses](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-and-container-status) to build the info. If I need to re-calculate it, maybe I can use [the kubectl sourcecode](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/pkg/kubectl)? Does anyone know where I can find the relevant bit? (I have very limited golang experience)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to show the exact same information as `kubectl get pods`. Please see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74722781/7129053

Answer (score 10):

The short answer is typically you don't have to calculate the 'Status' on the client since it's calculated at the server level.

To illustrate:

The standard way that you are trying to print with `kubectl get pods`, in the Kubernetes code base is called [Human Readable](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/20b01afecbba85c53b58711b07049e8c1b764b2d/staging/src/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/get/humanreadable_flags.go). This method uses [ServerPrint](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/20b01afecbba85c53b58711b07049e8c1b764b2d/staging/src/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/get/get.go#L273), which defaults to the [Kubernetes TablePrinter](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/20b01afecbba85c53b58711b07049e8c1b764b2d/staging/src/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/get/get.go#L274). The [TablePrinter type is defined here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/4477bf02f211093b32cf58f64aa42aff77daea61/staging/src/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/get/table_printer.go#L34).

As you can see the `PrintObj` function for the TablePrinter gets delegated [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/20b01afecbba85c53b58711b07049e8c1b764b2d/staging/src/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/get/table_printer.go#L41). It delegates to the appropriate [Kubernetes resource PrintObj](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/cli-runtime/pkg/printers/interface.go#L35).  Also, that delegation comes together with the configured [HumanPrintFlags](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/20b01afecbba85c53b58711b07049e8c1b764b2d/staging/src/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/get/get.go#L236) and saving the original [printer](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/20b01afecbba85c53b58711b07049e8c1b764b2d/staging/src/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/get/get.go#L258).

Also, you see that in [humanreadable_glags.go](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/4477bf02f211093b32cf58f64aa42aff77daea61/staging/src/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/get/humanreadable_flags.go) it's including `k8s.io/cli-runtime/pkg/printers`, and you see that it's instantiating a [printers.NewTablePrinter](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/9815cda4bf18ea1628a043fc3b78f99183bd1ee0/staging/src/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/get/humanreadable_flags.go#L88) which is defined in `k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/printers`.

The actual function to print that gets called is this [PrintObj](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/4477bf02f211093b32cf58f64aa42aff77daea61/staging/src/k8s.io/cli-runtime/pkg/printers/tableprinter.go#L94) and you can see that it handles 3 cases since in some cases the server returns a table and some not (looks like < 1.16 cases).

You also see that in the above case none of the code in https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/4477bf02f211093b32cf58f64aa42aff77daea61/pkg/printers/internalversion is used, so that [calculation](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/4477bf02f211093b32cf58f64aa42aff77daea61/pkg/printers/internalversion/printers.go#L444) happens behind the kube-apiserver side.

Keep in mind that this is the Human Readable printer and there other types of printers defined here (depending on the options): https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/staging/src/k8s.io/cli-runtime/pkg/printers

Comment: Most of the links you defined are broken.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. Stuff changes.

Comment: Updated the links... seems like the moved the code.

Comment: How can we simply get a notification if all the containers in a Pod finish and Pod life-cycle becomes `COMPLETED`? Any example would be appreciated.

Comment: @Rico protip: if you press a `y` shortcut (just a single keypress) while on any code or directory listing github page - it will give you a canonical url to that very commit: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/pkg/printers/internalversion -> `y` -> https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/5b4a7805c8c60ee21bcec307e658d8d4da4920bc/pkg/printers/internalversion

Comment: Thanks @zerkms. Fixed the answer and added more clarity.  This part is of the K8s code is a bit confusing but I supposed it's meant to handle all the use cases from all the K8s resources.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to re-calculate it. See [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/printers/internalversion/printers.go#L558)

Answer (score 1):

you should use restClient to get raw table output
[Receiving resources as Tables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#receiving-resources-as-tables)

the calculation is more complicated than you think,like `Age` field,in kubernetes,the code:
[func HumanDuration(d time.Duration) string {...}](https://github.com/kubernetes/apimachinery/blob/19377c9f105d03037e842e151d4605fef730b073/pkg/util/duration/duration.go#L48)